# How to use camel for synchronous behaviour and sequentially route processing?

Tags: apache-camel

I don't know if my question is quite correct but anyways.

The goal is to have a yml config file where you can configure the routes basically.
Like what file or regex should be used what operation like move, copy, zip or delete and if it is over sftp or not and more.

I am having a lot of problems with making it work sequentially since camel should only go through one route process the file or files that are necessary and then go to the next one since they could be dependend of each other.

Tried to go through the documentation of camel but I can't wrap my head around it.
Would be lovely if someone could help maybe even get in contact with me since I am pretty new to camel in general.

I have already had some code that was able to do many things with the routes but never got it to work sequentially.
I tried things like using start, continue and an end route where the routes would go with the continue route having the logic whats next but this did nothing.
Also tried limiting them to only one thread in the hopes they would wait but it did nothing and I did some stuff with the controlBus of camel but never saw literally anything change with that.

----- Update ------

I got it kinda working with the following code:

```
public void waitForRouteCompletion(String routeId) throws Exception {
        RouteController routeController = camelContext.getRouteController();
        ServiceStatus routeStatus = camelContext.getRouteController().getRouteStatus(routeId);
        if (routeStatus != null) {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            routeController.stopRoute(routeId);
            while (routeStatus.isStarted() || routeStatus.isStopping()) {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                routeStatus = camelContext.getRouteController().getRouteStatus(routeId);
                System.out.println(routeStatus);
            }
        }
    }
```

The only problem that now exists is that this method is supposed to stop the route but it's still reacting to files that fit to that route.
Goal is to only have the route active for one process.
When all the processes are done its supposed to repeat all of them in order again.

Comment: Please show your code because Camel does everything sequentially by default so I'm a bit surprised by your question

Comment: Read your comment a little late I will give you an update tomorrow since I got further but its still not perfect.
Before I had the problem that as I said it did everything simultaneously even if one wasnt fully finished, hence my question. 
Now I am at the state where it does actually wait for the route before but even if the last route does its thing and "closes" (according to the console) it still reacts to files that match the route.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I just updated it. 
Might be  good to know from you if there is any problem with the code.
Thats been literally the only way I got it working the way I want it to.